# Prove a vector equation (a + b - 2c = 0)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that a, b and c are vectors. (length of a is defined as |a|)

|a| = |b| = |c| = sqrt(2).
Given that 2c(a + b) = ab + 6(eq1)

Prove a + b - 2c = 0(eq2)

Suppose eq1 is true. a + b = 2c. Substituting in eq1 I get

=> 2c*2c = ab + 6

=> 4 c^2 = ab + 6

=> 4 |c|^2 = ab + 6

=> 4 * 2 - 6 = ab

=> ab = 2.

I am stack in here. This is an exercise of a friend and my vector skills are kinda rusty. Any insights ?

Comment: I'm not convinced by this. You're assuming $a+b = 2c$ which is exactly what you're trying to prove.

Comment: @AlgTop then I have no idea to be honest.. Can you guide me through this ?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how to do this, but I'll look at it. What field is your vector space over? and what exactly do you mean by $|c|$?

Comment: @AlgTop |c| I mean length of a vector. I got only this, as I said the exercise is not mine and the last time I used vector proofs was 5-6 years ago

Comment: @AlgTop maybe a tip will do the trick, let me know if you get anything

Comment: By $ab$ you mean dot product?

Comment: @helper yes its the dot product

Answer (score 1):

If $a + b = 2c$ and the lengths of $a$, $b$, and $c$ are the same, that means they're all the same vector, by the triangle inequality. So you just have to show that the vectors are all the same vector.

A promising approach would be to expand the all the dot products $vw$ in equation 1 into $|v||w|\space\text{cos}(\theta_v - \theta_w)$, then show that if the vectors $a$, $b$, and $c$ are not all the same, there is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks will check it out :)